# word-break css option has not effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm playing with the word-break css property, but can't seem to get it to work even with a simple example. My code is:

React:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h5 className="word-break">A very very long line..........</h5>
  );
}
```

css:

```
.word-break {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `break-word` is deprecated [`word-break MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `break-all`

```css
.word-break{
  word-break: break-all;  
}

h5{
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="word-break">A very very long line..........</h5>
```